# ¿Es posible hacer 'hash' a $x-variable?

Tags: php, mysqli, seguridad

Hola quisiera saber si es posible hacer lo siguiente:

```
 $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
 $nivel_auth = $_POST['nivel'];
 $hash_nivel = hash($nivel_auth);
 $con = "INSERT INTO usuario (nivel) VALUES ($hash_nivel) WHERE id_user=$id_user;
```

*Es bueno utilizar `hash` en `$var` ?*

*Sucederia algun error de "verificación" cuando consulte la `base de datos` para traer el `id_nivel` almacenado?*

En cuanto a **seguridad**, mejora o sigue siendo igual a una `$var`almacenada como tal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrige esta linea te falta "[":

```
 $nivel_auth = $_POST'nivel'];
```

Cambiala por:

```
$nivel_auth = $_POST['nivel'];
```

> **Es bueno utilizar hash en $var?**

Si debido a que le brinda una capa extra de seguridad a tu aplicación

> **Sucederia algun error de "verificación" cuando consulte la base de datos para traer el id_nivel almacenado?**

No tendría razón de ser que te diera error en la verificación porque cuando haces la comparación será siempre contra el mismo valor. Es decir hash del valor de la bd contra el hash del valor ingresado por el usuario por ejemplo.

> **En cuanto a seguridad, mejora o sigue siendo igual a una $varalmacenada como tal?**

Mejora mucho la seguridad, añade un nivel más porque si por alguna casualidad un tercero lograra capturar el valor en el trayecto no podría saber que tiene exactamente porque no "conoce" el valor original ingresado por lo que el dato para el tercero sería "inutil".